# OpenLayers Protocol specification

Tags: openlayers-2

Is there a specification for the protocol OpenLayers uses to communicate with the server?
I'm trying to reverse engineer what happens on GET, POST, PUT and DELETE, but I don't like to do it this way.

Example:

```
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer", {
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: '...',
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({})
    }),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't any particular protocol - its using a range of protocols, depending on what kind of layer you create. So if you create a WMS layer, its OGC WMS; it you create a TMS layer, its OSGEO TMS, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by specification but would looking at the source code help you work out what's going on?

If so look at http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/lib/OpenLayers/Protocol/HTTP.js

Comment: thats the way im doing now. i'm looking for a document that describes what kind of data is sent to the server to do GET, POST, PUT or DELETE. an what the server is sending as response. now i'm analyzing the calls via firebug but i want to know if there is a kind of standard